# Windows API for Socket SSL

Tags: c, windows, ssl, winsock

I am working on a C client/server program. Right now my code is just using normal winsock sockets to open a connection and send and receive. My next step is to add SSL/TLS to it.

I have played around with OpenSSL and embedTLS. Both worked, but ballooned my application size more than I want. I have done some research and found Secure Channel with Windows is what I might be after, however the documentation isn't good.

Other research led me into WinHTTP. But with my lack of knowledge, would this allow me to keep connections open with the server? Or does this just make a connection when it needs to send/recv?

Answer (score -1):

The `IWinHttpRequest`, the object-based wrapper around WinHttp also works.

```
IWinHttpRequest http = (IWinHttpRequest)CreateComObject(CLASS_WinHttpRequest);

http.open("GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55873932", false);

http.send(varEmpty);
```

You can see a full C example from Microsoft [on the documentation page:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winhttp/iwinhttprequest-open)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <objbase.h>

#include "httprequest.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "oleaut32.lib")

// IID for IWinHttpRequest.
const IID IID_IWinHttpRequest =
{
  0x06f29373,
  0x5c5a,
  0x4b54,
  {0xb0, 0x25, 0x6e, 0xf1, 0xbf, 0x8a, 0xbf, 0x0e}
};

int main()
{
    // Variable for return value
    HRESULT    hr;

    // Initialize COM
    hr = CoInitialize( NULL );

    IWinHttpRequest *  pIWinHttpRequest = NULL;

    BSTR            bstrResponse = NULL;
    VARIANT         varFalse;
    VARIANT         varEmpty;

    CLSID           clsid;

    VariantInit(&varFalse);
    V_VT(&varFalse)   = VT_BOOL;
    V_BOOL(&varFalse) = VARIANT_FALSE;

    VariantInit(&varEmpty);
    V_VT(&varEmpty) = VT_ERROR;

    hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1",
                           &clsid);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid,
                              NULL,
                              CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                              IID_IWinHttpRequest,
                              (void **)&pIWinHttpRequest);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Open WinHttpRequest.
        BSTR bstrMethod  = SysAllocString(L"GET");
        BSTR bstrUrl = SysAllocString(L"https://microsoft.com");
        hr = pIWinHttpRequest->Open(bstrMethod,
                                    bstrUrl,
                                    varFalse);
        SysFreeString(bstrMethod);
        SysFreeString(bstrUrl);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Send Request.
        hr = pIWinHttpRequest->Send(varEmpty);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Get Response text.
        hr = pIWinHttpRequest->get_ResponseText(&bstrResponse);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Print the response to a console.
        wprintf(L"%.256s",bstrResponse);
    }

    // Release memory.
    if (pIWinHttpRequest)
        pIWinHttpRequest->Release();
    if (bstrResponse)
        SysFreeString(bstrResponse);

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is using a request to a website. I just want to use sockets and use my own protocol to communicate between each other.